Gitlab pipeline not starting
My pipeline suddenly stopped launching. I'm getting an error on a file that has not been modified in 5 months. Here's what's on the .gitlab-ci.yml :
include:
  - template: Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - init
  - validate
  - deploy si-core
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  TF_STATE_NAME: default
  TF_CACHE_KEY: default
  COMPONENT: "none"
  TF_PROJECT_DIR: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"

.base-common: &base-common
  before_script:
    - source ${TF_PROJECT_DIR}/checkParams.sh $ENV $TF_VAR_auth_token
    - mkdir ${TF_PROJECT_DIR}/credentials
    - echo $ENV_SA_TERRAFORM_READ_STATE | base64 -d > ${TF_PROJECT_DIR}/credentials/sa-terraform-read-state.json
    - cd "${TF_ROOT}"
    - gitlab-terraform init
    - curl -O -L https://github.com/env0/terratag/releases/download/v0.2.3/terratag_0.2.3_linux_amd64.tar.gz
    - tar -xvf terratag_0.2.3_linux_amd64.tar.gz
    - ./terratag -tags="component=${COMPONENT},environment=${ENV}" -rename=false
    - cd ${TF_PROJECT_DIR}
  tags:
    - ci

.common: &common
  when: manual
  <<: *base-common

.variables-integ: &variables-integ
  ENV_FILE: "terraform.auto.tfvars"
  ENV: "integ"
  TF_ROOT: "${TF_PROJECT_DIR}/${ENV}"
  ENV_SA_TERRAFORM_READ_STATE: "${SA_TERRAFORM_READ_STATE_INTEG_NIJI}"
  ENV_SA_TERRAFORM: "${SA_TERRAFORM_INTEG_NIJI}"

validate-integ:
  variables:
    <<: *variables-integ
  <<: *common
  extends: .terraform:validate

deploy-si-core-integ:
  variables:
    <<: *variables-integ
    STAGE: "available"
  stage: deploy si-core
  trigger: GIREVE/gireve-gcp/si-core-infra
  needs: ["validate-integ"]

build-integ:
  variables:
    <<: *variables-integ
  <<: *common
  extends: .terraform:build
  needs: ["deploy-si-core-integ"]

deploy-integ:
  variables:
    <<: *variables-integ
  <<: *base-common
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build-integ
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /^feature\//'
      when: manual
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $TF_AUTO_DEPLOY == "true"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual

And this is the error that I get:
Unable to create pipeline
'build-integ' job needs 'deploy-si-core-integ' job, but 'deploy-si-core-integ' is not in any previous stage
Any idea why I'm getting this error? anything changed in the way Gitlab pipelines work lately?
